# how to get started with using version one java script sdk

Tags: javascript, versionone

I am looking for a good getting started guide for using version one java Script
SDK.I am using eclipse IDE.Please suggest the project structure for a webapp project using it.

here is a [link](http://blogs.versionone.com/agile-development/2013/02/20/developing-custom-versionone-apps-101-series-guide/) that i got which has some info.

Also suggest the documentation for the version one java script SDK.

Comment: I don't know of a guide or documentation, but this is an express app that uses it to display the stories in the backlog. https://github.com/walkerrandolphsmith/VersionOne.Planr

Answer (score 1):

I have created a article, http://walkerrandolphsmith.com/blog/v1sdk/, that describes a minimal setup to start using the SDK. In brief the application is a Node app that requires two dependencies: The v1sdk and a AJAX library.

In case the link becomes stale I will condense the article.

```
npm init --yes
npm install --save v1sdk axios
```

Create a file `server.js`

```
const axios = require('axios');
const v1sdk = require('v1sdk/dist/index');
const sdk = v1sdk.default;
const axiosConnector = v1sdk.axiosConnector;

const axiosConnectedSdk = axiosConnector(axios)(sdk);
const v1 = axiosConnectedSdk('V1Host', 'v1Instance')
            .withCreds('v1User', 'v1Password');
v1.query({
    'from': 'PrimaryWorkitem',
    'select': [
        'Name'
    ]
}).then(assets => {
    console.log(assets);
});
```

From the command line run, `node server.js`